# Passing React context through an HOC to a wrapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, higher-order-components

Is there a way that you can pass context through a React higher order component to a the component it wraps?

I have a HOC that receives context from its parent and utilizes that context to perform a basic, generalized action and then wraps a child component that also needs to access that same context to perform actions. Examples:

**HOC:**

```
export default function withACoolThing(WrappedComponent) {
  return class DoACoolThing extends Component {
    static contextTypes = {
      actions: PropTypes.object,
    }

    @autobind
    doAThing() {
      this.context.actions.doTheThing();
    }

    render() {
      const newProps = {
        doAThing: this.doAThing,
      };

      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...newProps} {...this.context} />
      );
    }
  }
};
```

**Wrapped Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { autobind } from 'core-decorators';
import withACoolThing from 'lib/hocs/withACoolThing';


const propTypes = {
  doAThing: PropTypes.func,
};

const contextTypes = {
  actions: PropTypes.object,
};

@withACoolThing
export default class SomeComponent extends PureComponent {

  @autobind
  doSomethingSpecificToThisComponent(someData) {
    this.context.actions.doSomethingSpecificToThisComponent();
  }

  render() {
    const { actions } = this.context;

    return (
      <div styleName="SomeComponent">
        <SomeOtherThing onClick={() => this.doSomethingSpecificToThisComponent(someData)}>Do a Specific Thing</SomeOtherThing>
        <SomeOtherThing onClick={() => this.props.doAThing()}>Do a General Thing</SomeOtherThing>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SomeComponent.propTypes = propTypes;
SomeComponent.contextTypes = contextTypes;
```

Passing `{...this.context}` in the HOC does not work. `this.context` is an empty `{}` as long as the wrapped component is wrapped by the HOC. Please help? Is there any way to pass down context that doesn't involve passing it as props??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Problem:**

> If contextTypes is not defined, then context will be an empty object.

**The Solution:**

Set `WrappedComponent.contextTypes` *inside* the HOC.

**Explanation:**

In the unfixed code, `contextTypes` for `SomeComponent` isn't being set. When `SomeComponent` gets decorated by `@withACoolThing`, any changes you make to `SomeComponent` are actually happening to `DoACoolThing`, and `contextTypes` for `SomeComponent` never gets set so it ends up being an empty object `{}`.

**Side Note:**

Because you are expanding `this.context` in the HOC and passing it down as props here:

`<WrappedComponent {...this.props} {...newProps} {...this.context} />`

You should have things like `this.props.actions.doTheThing` available in the child component.