# How to use reach router with React Context API?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, reach-router

I use reach router like this below before and it works fine

```
.....
<Router>
   <ComponentA path="/:id">
   <ComponentB path="/">
<Router>
....
```

I decided to refactor my code with context, and the code is refactored to something like this:

```
<GlobalContextProvider>
  <GlobalContext.Consumer>
  {( context) =>{
  return(
  .....
   <Router>
      <ComponentA path="/:id">
      <ComponentB path="/">
   <Router>
   ....
  }
```

After the refactor, the ComponentA is not working properly, as the url param prop id is not passed

In the ComponentA.js , test like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props;
    console.log(id);    // return undefined
  }
```

Also when I `console.log(this.props)` , it returns the same result as `this.context`

Can someone help me understand why this is happening? How to refactor with context properly?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I finally figure out this issue:

`ComponentA` is wrapped with HOC, and by adding `{...this.props}` to ComposedComponent,
[image]
[image]

`ComponentA` can access the url params from `this.props`

Please refer this issue [Passing React context through an HOC to a wrapped component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45873414/passing-react-context-through-an-hoc-to-a-wrapped-component)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it was working at first.

To access the param value, you have to do it this way :

```
const { match } = props;
const { params } = match;
const { id } = params;
```

You might need to wrap your component into withRouter(...)

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
class MyComp extends PureComponent {...}
export default withRouter(MyComp);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use `reach-router` instead of `react-router` though

Comment: Did you try another key word rather than id ? Since it might be overwrite by the global consumer.

Comment: I didn't use  `id` for my project, it was something else. I use `id` just as an example to describe this issue.